# IOS view updates to default IB layout whenever an action is fired

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have a project that has most of its layout logic in the IB.  Some of the positioning I want to update dynamically so I put it in the viewDidAppear:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
// Fill array of button tools
buttonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
               self.filterButton, self.bulgeButton, self.stickerButton, self.textButton, self.drawButton, self.invertedBulgeButton, nil];

// Position button tools
int const X_POSITION = 175; // The x position of the tool buttons
int yPosition = 0; // The x position of the tool buttons
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(X_POSITION, yPosition, 100, 100); // The position and size of the tool buttons

// Loop through buttons and set properties
for (UIButton *button in buttonArray) {
    frame.origin.y = yPosition;
    button.frame = frame;
    yPosition += 75;
    button.hidden = false;
}
}
```

The problem I have is that whenever I press another button all the formatting I applied in the viewDidAppear is undone and the buttons positioning are changed to what they are in the IB.   How can I prevent my buttons from moving to the locations set in the IB?

edit: Here is some of the code that will cause the positioning to change:

```
// Undoes most recent edit to photo
- (IBAction)undoButtonPress:(id)sender {
    [self undoImage];
}

- (void)undoImage {
    // TODO:  Add all the other current actions.... none of them work because they need to be checked for here
    // Remove tools for the current action
    self.imageSticker.image = nil;
    [self refreshImageText];

    currentAction = NONE;
    self.mainImage.image = [_images pop];

}
// after done editing the text, this resets the text fields so you can create a second text
- (void) refreshImageText{
    self.hiddenTextField.text = @"";
    self.imageText.text = @"";

    self.imageText.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
    [self.imageText setCenter:self.view.center];
}
```

Comment: are you using auto layout?

Comment: You have to show us the code that is being ran when you do these "actions" that reset your layout.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to update the constraints, not the actual frames of your objects. So if you add your button frame y constraints as an `IBOutlet` you can edit it easily.

Here is a really cool tool to play with autolayout constraints:
https://autolayoutconstraints.com/

Comment: Currently I don't have any constraints on those buttons, just other components in that view....  Do I need to add constraints to those buttons also or is there a way to do it with the frame?

Comment: yes, or programmatically create them and add them after the view has has laid out it it's subviews.

Comment: Ah that's a pain.... Also I noticed that the sizes I set programmatically are being reverted to what is in IB.  Is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that it is AutoLayout that is messing with my positioning.  I was able to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to true to prevent AutoLayout from messing with my settings:

```
// Loop through buttons and set properties
for (UIButton *button in buttonArray) {
    frame.origin.y = yPosition;
    button.frame = frame;
    yPosition += 75;
    button.hidden = false;
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
}
```